# Question about a Medical Bill

Tags: billing

I went to a dermatologist and had a my moles checked for skin cancer. When the lady was done she said she found 2 that were questionable. I asked her how much it would be to have them removed and she gave 2 different prices. One was for removal only and the other was removal and a biopsy. Before they removed them and sent them for a biopsy, I asked her if that was my total price, she said yes. I have no insurance so i went ahead paid the bill in full before i left. Anyways, yesterday i get a bill from the lab that did the biopsy. I was never told by the dermatologist that there would be a bill from the lab also. When i got the bill, i called the dermatologist and they acted like it was my fault, because i should have known better. So my question is, should they be liable for my bill since they failed to tell me about the lab charge. Thanks!

Comment: Along with the answer by keshlam, I just wanted to state, in most cases, if you received service, then you will have to pay for the services you received.  It isn't a great situation, but there is one other thing you can do that can help save you money.  Without insurance, if you are willing to pay a doctor out of pocket, in full, then in some cases they may be willing to charge you less.  This isn't guaranteed, but you can easily ask, would the doctor be willing to charge less if you pay in full at the time of service.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't make them pay this cost. It's annoying, but this is standard medical billing practice, and you didn't quite ask the right question. Take it as a learning experience.

Comment: This is not a given: over two rounds of IVF I have paid the genetics lab directly once; and the IVF clinic prepaid a purchase order to the lab that they initiated, and I reimbursed them.  It is worth confirming every itemized procedure code to make sure none show up on both bills.

Comment: Valid point, @user662852. However, separate billing is the norm. If you think this is bad, wait until you're dealing with a hospital, where each department may bill separately.

Comment: So, what would be covered by the extra charged by the dermatologists for biopsy?

Comment: Im not sure DJohnM , Thats were i feel liked im being duped. The way they told me, was misleading. Well, like keshlam said, i will have to chalk this up as a learning experience. Thanks for the answers.